# Shifting of axis title and sub-title in Gnuplot histogram

Tags: gnuplot

Mr data file is

```
# test.dat
# Sample No.    Phenol Red      Neutral Red      Bromophenol Blue    Bromocresol Green      Mixed Indicator
1                  80                69               223               222                       130
2                  89                62               321               267                       160
3                  92                67               248               276                       147
```

Gnuplot code is

```
#
#
###
reset session
###
set terminal postscript eps enhanced colour font 'Times-Roman,12' size 6in,4in  
set output "test.eps"
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set style line 1 lt 4 lw 1 lc rgb "#4169E1"
set style line 2 lt 4 lw 1 lc rgb "#2E8B57"
set style line 3 lt 5 lw 1 lc rgb "#FF4500"
set style line 4 lt 4 lw 1 lc rgb "#FAD02C"
set style line 5 lt 4 lw 1 lc rgb "#FF0080"
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set xtics out scale 1.5 
set ytics out scale 1.5
set ytics nomirror
set yrange [0:350]
set key off
set tics font ", 16"
set xlabel "Sample No. " font ",16"
set ylabel "Moisture Content ({/Symbol \155}g of H_{2}O/g of melt)" font ",16"
set key samplen 2 spacing 1.65 font ",14" width -1.0
set key inside left horizontal  
set style fill solid border
set style histogram clustered gap 1 title textcolor lt -1
# ----------------------------------------
set rmargin screen 0.9
set lmargin screen 0.1
set bmargin screen 0.4
# ----------------------------------------
set style data histogram
plot \
newhistogram "Direct titration", \
'test.dat' using 2:xtic(1) ls 4 axes x1y1 title "Phenol Red", \
'' u 3 ls 5 axes x1y1 title "Neutral Red", \
newhistogram "Back-titration", \
'test.dat.dat' using 4:xtic(1) ls 1 axes x1y1 title "Bromophenol Blue", \
'' u 5 ls 2 axes x1y1 title "Bromocresol Green", \
'' u 6 ls 3 axes x1y1 title "Mixed Indicator"
# ----------------------------------------
##
```

Script works fine. I would like to provide more spacing between the tick labels (1,2,3) and the sub-title (Direct titration and Back-titration) as well as spacing between the sub-titles and axis title. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

`set xlabel offset 0, -1` will shift both the subtitles and the axis title downward by one character height.

`set xlabel "\nTEXT"` will create a two-line axis label and place TEXT on the second line.

Modifying your xlabel command to be

```
set xlabel "\nSample No. " font ",16" offset 0,-1
```

will make both those changes.